# Titanium Studio JavaScript - adding buttons to table views

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

Is it possible to add buttons to table views? I am trying to create a screen that resembles a settings screen on the iPhone.

I know you are able to add the little arrow that represents that the list has a child but what I'm specifically looking for is how to add a plus button to the right side of my table view.

Comment: Are you using Alloy or classic Titanium (Javascript only)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a button to the row. That means you need to create a custom row. It's much simpler. Try the following

```
function createRow(){  
    var tableRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        hasChild : false,
        width    : '100%',
        height   : 55,
    });

    var addButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title    : '+',
        width    : 40,
        height   : 40,
        right    : '3%'
    });

    addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert("Hey, you clicked + button");
    });

    tableRow.add(addButton);

    return tableRow;
}
```

The above code creates a customized row. Hope it helps you.
Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @ThomasMcDonald: From your previous question, assuming that you are using classic Titanium.